# ReactJS Props and bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't do something like this.

```js
loadPostsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/allPosts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({posts:data, items:data});
            //this.setState({items:data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url,status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
},

loadUserFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/user',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({user:data.local});
            //console.log(this.state.user);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url,status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
},

getInitialState: function() {
   return {
      posts: [],
      items: [],
      user:  []
   }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadPostsFromServer();
    this.loadUserFromServer();

    //this.setState({items: this.state.posts}); 
    //setInterval(this.loadPostsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
},

render: function() {
    <div className="Posts">
        <List user={this.state.user} posts={this.state.items} />
    </div>
}
```

Where List can be something like this and can't do the this.props.user print

```
var List = React.createClass({ //has to be called list
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>{this.props.user}</p>
            <ul>
            {
                this.props.posts.map(post){
                    return (<p>{post.title}</p>)
                })
            }
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

but can do this:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<p>{this.props.user}</p>)
    }
});
```

Basically I'm passing two props in my real function, and the ajax call is delivering down a array user, with user info, and array post with post info. I can display the post info fine, and the user info is complete as well, however I cannot actually display the user info received from the ajax get call. I printed out the state of the array as well and it was complete and filled. However passed down it would return messages like cannot read {this.props.user.firstName} and such, however writing it the second way and not including posts, it works fine. How can I use both props in a map function?

Comment: You've got a typo: `</o>` in place of `</p>`

Comment: fixed the type but not the issue :/ thanks

Comment: You should also post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, in render function, you always need a wrap tag to make React work. You should add `<div>` tag to the `render` of `List` component.

```
var List = React.createClass({ //has to be called list
render: function() {
    return (
       <div> <-- ALWAYS HAS A WRAP TAG
        <p>{this.props.user}</p>
        <ul>
        {
            this.props.posts.map(post){
                return (<p>{post.title}</p>)
            })
        }
        </ul>

       </div>
    )
}
});
```

This code below works because there is `<p>` to wrap contents.

```
var List = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (<p> <-- WRAP TAG
          {this.props.user}
          </p>)
}
});
```

Comment: ahh I feel so dumb, I usually do it for my parent, but I didn't notice that I stopped doing it for ALL my children components! Thank you.

Comment: I have a small question, but in the mapping, is it possible to call this.props.user because it seems like it doesn't work since it commits to a function with this.props.post. After testing it, it seemed so. Is there a way to utilize this.props.user in my mapping?

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out, I would just set it as a variable under the render function, and then call it as { variable }

Comment: you can set reference for `this` of the component by set `var self = this`  in `render` function and use `self.props.user` in your mapping. Or you can use binding function. `this.props.posts.map(post){.....}.bind(this)`

Comment: Lets say for example I wanted to loop through self.props.user, in my mapping, and if a certain condition was met in that loop than a variable style would equal red or green. Is it good practice to just write for(var i = 0; i < self.prop.user.length; i++), because render will be called everytime the state changes causing reassigning of variables right? Creating a lot of iterations.